# FOR loop condition inside PostgreSQL function

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-insert, generate-series

Given below is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE gtab86
(
  mlid integer DEFAULT nextval('seq_gtab86_id'::regclass),
  acyrid integer,
  lmonth integer,
  islocked boolean
)
```

- In this table `lmonth` is the month  fied, and `acyrid` is the year denoting value for example 1.
- I wrote the following `Function` to insert into `gtab86`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createmonthlock(iacyrid integer) 
    RETURNS void AS '
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,1); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,2);
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,3); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,4); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,5); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,6); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth)VALUES (iacyrid,7); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth)VALUES (iacyrid,8); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth)VALUES (iacyrid,9); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth)VALUES (iacyrid,10); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth)VALUES (iacyrid,11); 
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth)VALUES (iacyrid,12);
END;' 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

As you can see, insert into is repeated 12 times (for 12 `lmonth` field rows).
How to make it only one insert query?
Is it possible to use `for 0 to 12` kind things inside a *function*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `insert .. select` based on `generate_series()`.

You also don't need PL/pgSQL for this, a plain SQL function will do:

```
create or replace function createmonthlock(iacyrid integer) 
 returns void
as
$body$
   INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) 
   select iacyrid, num
   from generate_series(1,12) num;
$body$
language sql;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer. You just missed the `returns void` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple rows with a single `INSERT` statement:

`INSERT INTO gtab86(acyrid, lmonth) VALUES (iacyrid,1), (iacyrid,2), (iacyrid,3), (iacyrid,4), (iacyrid,5), (iacyrid,6), (iacyrid,7), (iacyrid,8), (iacyrid,9), (iacyrid,10), (iacyrid,11), (iacyrid,12);`